# hide default navigation bar in navigation controller in ios 5

Tags: ios5, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, storyboard, show-hide

I am programming for iOS 5 using storyboards.
I am trying to create an app with a navigation controller.
In my app I want some view controllers to have the navigation bar and in some I dont.

I am using the following [link](http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/using-storyboards-to-make-navigation-based-iphone-apps/1445/) as my guidance to create one.

This is how I am programmatically hiding the navigation bar:

In MyAppDelegate I declared a variable:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;
```

In my UIViewController, which is the first UIViewController, I did the following

```
- (void)viewDidload
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    [super viewDidUnload];

    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}
```

But this is not working...

How do I make it work?

Answer (score 3):

Raj,

Try adding these two functions to your UIViewController:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
}

- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Select `Navigation Controller` in `story board`, go to `attributes inspector`, there's a checkbox called `Shows Navigation Bar`, uncheck it.

If setting `setNavigationBarHidden:YES` in `viewWillAppear:`, the animation (hiding navigation bar) will still present.

This's the main difference.

Comment: I am on ios 4. so no story board